# Is there any idea to control the contrast and brightness of webcam in web apps in mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on react js project that needs to open the camera of the device and control the contrast and brightness. I'm using `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` with those constraints

```
CAPTURE_OPTIONS = {
  audio: false,
  video: { facingMode: "environment",  width: width, height: height, aspectRatio: width/height, pan: true, tilt: true, zoom: true, brightness: true, contrast: true, saturation: true,sharpness: true   }
}
```

when using chrome in windows OS, I can manage brightness, contrast, and zoom but when we try to open it using Android or IOS browsers we can't manage the brightness and contrast.
Is there any Idea how we can enable the control of brightness and contrast in mobile browsers?

Comment: Check this out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Image_Capture_API
It's still experimental, not supported in Firefox but it offers the capabilities you want.

Comment: I checked before but I need to support safari mobile as well also we are focused on the brightness and contrast of the camera  but still not working in the mobile browsers (chrome, safari)